# Accessing json data from ajax using express.js

Tags: javascript, express, handsontable

I'm pulling data from HandsOnTable and sending it to my Node.JS and Expess.JS backend for saving. As per the example here (http://docs.handsontable.com/0.20.2/tutorial-load-and-save.html) I'm doing a json.stringify on the data prior to sending it off via an AJAX GET.

My problem is in accessing the data once received on the backend. I'm using body-parser to access json objects like this: req.body.xxx; however I'd like to be able to access each row and field e.g. 'Bob'.

Any ideas? Below is my json data.

```
{"data":[["Bob",null,"PHD",null],["Julie",null,"test",null],["Stan",null,"Masers",null]]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following function to access data at specified row and column:

```
function accessColumn(data, row, column) {
    return data.data[row][column];
}
console.log(accessColumn(data, 0, 0)); // "Bob"
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do simple loop over the data:

Getting all fields and do your processing over each one

```
for(var i =0;i<t.data.length;i++) 
  for(var y =0;y<t.data[i].length;y++) {
     console.log(t.data[i][y]); 
  }
```

or get whatever you need according to index using

```
t.data[x][y]
```

- Supposing t is avariable filled of your data